# How do I retain the colors of my WPF ComboBox when I select an item?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a WPF ComboBox from an online example . . .

```
<!-- Combo Box for specifying current projector-->
<ComboBox Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,660,0,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" 
          Name="comboBoxProj" Text="Projector" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" SelectionChanged="comboBoxVersion_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj1" Foreground="Orange">Proj1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj2" Foreground="Red">Proj2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj3" Foreground="Green">Proj3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj4" Foreground="Blue">Proj4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj5" Foreground="Cyan">Proj5</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj6" Foreground="Magenta">Proj6</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj7" Foreground="Purple">Proj7</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj8" Foreground="Yellow">Proj8</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The dropdown list displays each item in a different color. When I select an item off the dropdown, the text appears properly as the value of the collapsed combobox, but just in black letters.   What's the simplest way for the text to be shown in its original color from the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it this way:

```
<ComboBox Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,660,0,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" 
          Name="comboBoxProj" Text="Projector" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" SelectionChanged="comboBoxVersion_SelectionChanged" TextElement.Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedValue.Foreground}">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj1" Foreground="Orange">Proj1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj2" Foreground="Red">Proj2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj3" Foreground="Green">Proj3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj4" Foreground="Blue">Proj4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj5" Foreground="Cyan">Proj5</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj6" Foreground="Magenta">Proj6</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj7" Foreground="Purple">Proj7</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Proj8" Foreground="Yellow">Proj8</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Foreground` property in the SelectionChanged event handler:

```
private void comboBoxVersion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).Foreground = ((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Foreground;
}
```